# How to capture current Status code in ASP.NET CORE 3.1 Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-3.1, http-status-codes

I have written method that returns the result in the object. I need to capture current HttpStatusCode rather than I create my own and save in the following object before returning a result

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateUser([FromBody]UsereDto user)  
    {
        try
        {
            var data = UserService.CreateUser(user);

            
            var result = new ResultDto
            {
                Ok = true,
                Data = data,
                Error = "No",
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode. ???????????????
            };

            
            return Ok(result);
        }
        catch(Exception exp)
        {
            var errorResult = new ResultDto
            {
                Ok = false,
                Data = null,
                Error = exp.ToString()
                StatusCode =  ????????????
            };

            return Ok(errorResult);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't capture existing http code
you can manually enter http codes yourself.

For Example:
Created Code=201
Error Code =400
BadRequest:301
NotFound:404

```
return StatusCode(200,object);
```

You can also return it this way.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure what do you want to achieve or why do you even want that since HTTP Response already will contain an http status, so returning it additionally in a JSON response does not add more information than is already available.

But you can just hardcode the status since it is always 200 in your example, unless there is some error during serialization of the response, etc.

Right after your `???` line you do return an `Ok()` response that will return 200.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create your own status code inside dto...

`return Ok(errorResult);` will return 200 with error and this is bad.
Instead, you should return BadRequestResult(errorResult) and ui will receive 500 result containing your DTO.

Also, instead of `return Ok(result);`, you can return `OkResult(result)` and this will return 200 to UI, also containing your DTO...

Also, you should extract Dto creation to it's own method in separate class, to follow DRY and single responsibility principles..